# Gitorious Ruby Apache SSL Error

Tags: git, ssl, apache2, passenger, vhosts

I have installed gitorious ruby application, configured apache passenger and vhost. Everything works fine but I can't git push

```
[17:41:29] Thiago: git push https://usa5.vsnetwork.net/testedogit/testedogit
error: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt     
CRLfile: none while accessing https://usa5.vsnetwork.net/testedogit/testedogit/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

My vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName usa5.vsnetwork.net
   DocumentRoot /var/www/gitorious/public
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/gitorious/public
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
   BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Specs: Ubuntu 11.04, Apache 2.2, Ruby Enterprise 1.8, Passenger 3.0.8

Anyone knows how chould I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitorious doesn't support https push at the moment but there is a repository which implements it using JRuby: https://gitorious.org/gitorious/mutt

Answer (score 0):

did You had enabled apache passenger module?

## a2enmod passenger